# Display Popup Window in a Page having Slider functionality in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap development. How to display a Popup window in a Page which is implemented using Page Slider functionality in PhoneGap.?
I implemented Popup window and Page Slider individually, then it is working fine, but if I integrated both popup window is not working.
How should I fix this.? Can anyone help me

Comment: try jquery mobile..or check this http://amazingslider.com/examples/jquery-slider-with-image-and-video-lightbox/

Comment: thanks for your response Aravin. I am asking about Page Slider not Image Slider or Video Slider in html